# Are グラス and ガラス alternative spellings of the same word?

Tags: word-choice, spelling

As in the title: Are グラス and ガラス alternative spellings of the same word?

I'm going through a 2級 prep book for vocabulary and it has

ワイングラス = wine glass

but

ガラスのコップ = glass (for drinking)

and

窓のガラス = window glass

Are グラス and ガラス the same or do I have to be careful when to use which?

Comment: AFAIK, ガラス is for the _material_ "glass", while グラス is for the thing that holds a liquid you're about to drink.

Comment: I'll just add that the origins are different as well, グラス being from the English, while ガラス is from Dutch 'Glas'.

Comment: @Ash Interesting. And funny how the same word became two different words : )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While people will likely understand you if you mix them up, it's better to use proper one:

`ガラス` = glass (material)

- 吹きガラス (glass blowing)
- ガラスの皿 (glass plate)

`グラス` = a glass (for drinking)

- タンブラーグラス (tumbler glass)
- ワイングラス (wine glass), グラスワイン ([drink] a glass of wine)
- カクテルグラス (cocktail glass)
- ミキシンググラス (mixing glass)

`~グラス` = some other things made from glass, or have "glass" in the English name:

- サングラス (sunglasses), オペラグラス (opera glasses)
- ステンドグラス (stained glass)
- アワーグラス (hourglass)

Comment: Are these pronounced (in 標準語【ひょうじゅんご】) as ガラス【HHL】, グラス【LHL】, and グラス【HLL】, respectively?

Comment: Basically ガラス（０）、グラス（０or１）i.e. ガラス and グラス or グ↓ラス. When they are component of a word compound in the form of ＿＿グラス, they have downstep before the last two moras i.e. 吹きガ↓ラス(3)、ワイング↓ラス(4). As for グラスワイン, it's グラスワ↓イン(4).